# Real-time aggregation on a table with millions of records

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

I'm dealing with an ever growing table which contains about 5 million records at the moment. About a 100000 new records are added daily.

The table contains information about ad campaigns, and is joined on query with another table:

```
CREATE TABLE `statistics` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ip_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `campaign_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `payout` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_converted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `converted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `created` (`created`),
    KEY `converted` (`converted`),
    KEY `campaign_id` (`campaign_id`),
    KEY `ip_range_id` (`ip_range_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The other table contains IP ranges:

```
CREATE TABLE `ip_ranges` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ip_range` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `ip_range` (`ip_range`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The aggregation query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    SUM(`payout`) AS `revenue`, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `statistics` WHERE `ip_range_id` = `IpRange`.`id`) AS `clicks`, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `statistics` WHERE `ip_range_id` = `IpRange`.`id` AND `is_converted` = 1) AS `conversions` 
FROM `ip_ranges` AS `IpRange` 
INNER JOIN `statistics` AS `Statistic` ON `IpRange`.`id` = `Statistic`.`ip_range_id`
GROUP BY `IpRange`.`id` 
ORDER BY `clicks` DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

The query takes about 20 seconds to complete.

This is what EXPLAIN returns:

```
id  select_type         table       type   possible_keys    key          key_len  ref               rows    Extra

1   PRIMARY             ip_range    index  PRIMARY          PRIMARY      4        NULL              306552  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY             statistic   ref    ip_range_id      ip_range_id  5        db.ip_range.id    8       Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  statistics  ref    ip_range_id      ip_range_id  5        func              8       Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  statistics  ref    ip_range_id      ip_range_id  5        func              8       Using where; Using index
```

Caching the clicks and conversions in the ip_ranges table as extra columns is not an option, because I need to be able to also filter on the campaign_id column (and possibly other columns in the future). So these aggregations need to be somewhat real-time.

What is the best strategy to do aggregation on large tables on multiple dimensions and near real-time?

**Note that I'm not necessarily looking to just make the query better, but I'm also interested in strategies that might involve other database systems (NoSQL) and/or distributing the data over different servers, etc**

Comment: Have you tried counting `clicks` and `conversions` with simply `count()` instead of subqueries? If so, is it fast enough?

Comment: No matter what anyone will tell you to use, from different types of queries and what not, there is a point where any relational database hangs while doing queries and in majority of cases the cause is slow hard drive. The strategy that is available to you, as a quick fix, is to increase the amount of RAM available to MySQL. Since you need to go through a lot of records, there is no "indexing strategy" that you can implement - you simply need to go trough these records to get a calculation out. Long story short - increase the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: @Vatev That would take just as long, if not longer, because it still has to calculate clicks, conversions and revenue for each IP range. But I also need them as subqueries so I can do the ORDER BY on those columns.

Comment: @N.B. I understand throwing more RAM at the problem might solve it, but only that would be a temporary solution. Besides, I'm already on 1GB with innodb_buffer_pool_size on a machine where there's 3GB (out of 24GB total) of free memory left at the moment.

Comment: The core of your problem is getting information to the CPU for calculation. The operation of finding the data and retrieving it is slow, because of mechanical drive, and you need most of your data. Sadly, when you have a lot of data that you need to go through, then that's it - you simply have to go through them. You are at the point where you need to increase your computing power, be it by making the current server better or by using multiple servers.

Comment: Let's say I have multiple servers at my disposal. What kind of strategy would be recommended here? I have never worked with partitioned or distributed data, but I'm willing to go that route. I'm also willing to use other database solutions (MongoDB) if that helps with this problem.

Comment: You split the data between multiple servers so each of them does a fraction of the work. MongoloidDb is a clever marketing trick, it's basically crap and all it does is that it lets OS schedule disk writes (which get cached, hence "performance"). Alternatively, avoiding all of that - try Percona TokuDB (it's MySQL with TokuDB storage engine). You might get better disk reads and up to 11x less data due to compression.

Comment: @Botch what I meant is pretty much Thorsten Kettner's answer. I guess I wasn't very clear about it. If you want to get faster than that you will have to precalculate the results and query those for reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks overly complicated. There is no need to query the same table again and again:

```
select
  sum(payout) as revenue, 
  count(*) as clicks, 
  sum(s.is_converted = 1) as conversions 
from ip_ranges r
inner join statistics s on r.id = s.ip_range_id
group by r.id 
order by clicks desc 
limit 20;
```

EDIT (after acceptance): As to your actual question on how to deal with a task like this:

You want to look at *all* the data in your table and you want your result to be *up-to-date*. Then there is no other option than to read all data (full table scans). If the tables are wide (i.e. have many columns) you may want to create covering indexes (i.e. indexes that contain all columns involved), so instead of reading the table, the index would be read. Well, what else? On full table scans it is recommendable to use parallel access, which MySQL doesn't provide, as far as I know. So you might want to switch to another DBMS. Then see what else the DBMS offers. Maybe the parallel querying would benefit from partitioning the tables. The last thing that comes to mind is hardware, i.e. more CPUs, faster drives etc.

Another option might be to remove old data from your tables. Say you need the details of the current year, but only the aggregated data for previous years. Then have another table old_statistics holding only the sums and counts needed, e.g.

```
table old_statistics
(
  ip_range_id,
  revenue,
  conversions
);
```

Then you'd aggregate the data from statistics, which would be much smaller then, because it would hold only data of the current year, and add old_statistics to get the results.

Comment: That's a good one. It actually cuts the execution time in half. The query is generated, so I'll have to make some changes in the code that's doing the generating, but that's another problem.

Comment: I've marked the question as answered, though it still isn't a long term solution. When dealing with, say, billions of records, this query would still be really slow. But I guess I'll post a new question that deals with strategies instead of queries specifically. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi thanks for accepting my answer. I've added a part to deal with your actual question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    SUM(`payout`) AS `revenue`, 
    SUM(case when `ip_range_id` = `IpRange`.`id` then 1 else 0 end) AS `clicks`, 
    SUM(case when `ip_range_id` = `IpRange`.`id` and `is_converted` = 1 then 1 else 0 end)  
      AS `conversions` 
FROM `ip_ranges` AS `IpRange` 
INNER JOIN `statistics` AS `Statistic` ON `IpRange`.`id` = `Statistic`.`ip_range_id`
GROUP BY `IpRange`.`id` 
ORDER BY `clicks` DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: And what exactly does this do? Why would anyone blindly use your query? What problem is it solving and why would it be faster? You still have the LIMIT clause there so you'll go through all the records and involve disk seeks.

Comment: That doesn't return the actual count of clicks and conversions.

Comment: @Botch: It should. Provided IpRange.id is unique of course. How are Madhivanan's numbers different from yours?